# VideoView not showing video only audio coming in android 4.0.3 only

Tags: android, audio, video, android-videoview

i have a basic example app to play video from res/raw. My problem is that it is not working(only audio playing) in android 4.0.3, but working in 3.2 , 4.3 , 4.4 (emulators). And on a real device  (micromax canvas 4 with android 4.2.1) it says app has stopped responding.?
My question how can i play it on all android and why is it not responding on my moblie??
and i have already searched on stackoverflow with no positive result..
    PLEASE HELP THANKS

this is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/vidvew"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my .java file

```
package com.example.tryit;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vidvew);
    String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +R.raw.cs;
    vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));
    vv.start();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Your app is crashing when your are playing a video on Android 4.0.3 on a REAL device ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding of the video properly. Android allows only certain types of file types to be played in the app. Please see the link below for more information -
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html